# Change variable SASS depending on platform

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I used Ionic2 RC3 for my application. I want to change the value of varible SASS depending on Platform. For example, I have a variable $statusbar-height which has value 0px if the device is Windows or Android, but 20px if the device is on IOS. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do that. My suggestion is to add an additional class if the device is iOS. Then with this class you can overwrite the default height of the status bar

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
$platform: android !default;
$primary: black !default;

@if $platform == android {
    $primary: red;
} @else if $platform == ios {
    $primary: green;
} @else {
    $primary: blue;
}

.primary_class {
    color : $primary;
}
```

Moreover, you can put the `$platform` variable in `./src/theme/variables.scss` : it will allow you to access this variable from any other SCSS file of your app.